# AppDomain.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, appdomain

When we used AppDomain.CreateInstance("Assembly name", Type name)
 and my class inherits from MarshalByRefObject
 what happen internally? Is it create a TransparetnProxy?

Code:

```
class Greet : MarshalByRefObejct
{
  ...
}

class test
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Second");
   ObjectHandle hObj = ad.CreateInstance("Test", args[0]);
  ....
 }
}
```

passing in args[0] = Greet

Comment: Does CreateInstance give call to RemotingProxy or Unwrap does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it creates a transparent proxy, which you get by unwrapping the object handle.

I find the [documentation and example for `ObjectHandle.Unwrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx) is quite informative, as is the general [`MarshalByRefObject` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You might also want to take a look at [CreateInstanceAndUnwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createinstanceandunwrap.aspx). If your code in Main and the Greet class were to share a common interface, you could cast hObj into your interface and call methods on it using the TransparentProxy.

Answer (score 1):

`AppDomain.CoCreateInstance()` takes two argument that which assembly and their type name.

And it returns an `ObjectHandle` used to create the instance of specified type in the assembly, and also provide the handle by which `wrap(serialized)` when it is instantiated and when it need  then it is `unwrap(deserialized)` return to real `Proxy`.